# code Analyser for c# and VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

m making a toool to check the coding standerd in run time means i m giving the standered in run to check for that i m creating a XML file for standered and cheking in a whole project from that XML file.
i have other functionality to give the comment before start the function.

code working fine in VB for comment

```
While oRead.Peek <> -1
                strLineIn = oRead.ReadLine().Trim
                intLineNo = intLineNo + 1
                Dim arr As String() = SplitWords(strLineIn)
                'To update the Progress Bar 
                setProgressBar(intLineNo, intLinesCount)

                If Not strLineIn.StartsWith("'") Then

                    If (strLineIn.Contains("Sub") Or strLineIn.Contains("Function")) _
                        And Not (strLineIn.Contains("End Sub") Or strLineIn.Contains("End Function")) _
                        And Not (strLineIn.Contains("Exit Sub") Or strLineIn.Contains("Exit Function")) _
                        And Not strLineIn.StartsWith("'") Then
                        Select Case Array.IndexOf(arr, "Sub")
                            Case 0, 1, 2
                                createErrorLog(strLineIn, fi.Name, intLineNo, "No Commnet Line for Sub Procedure", fi, strErroLogFile)
                        End Select
                        Select Case Array.IndexOf(arr, "Function")
                            Case 0, 1, 2
                                createErrorLog(strLineIn, fi.Name, intLineNo, "No Commnet line for Function", fi, strErroLogFile)
                        End Select
                    End If
                Else
                    'createErrorLog(processXMLComment(oRead), fi.Name, intLineNo, "No Commnet Line", fi)
                    strLineIn = processXMLComment(oRead, intLineNo)
                End If
                If Not strLineIn.Trim.StartsWith("'") Then
                    For intVar As Integer = 0 To DataType.Count - 1
                        If strLineIn.Contains(DataType(intVar).InnerText) Then
                            arr = SplitWords(strLineIn)
                            For inti As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 1
                                If arr(inti) = DataType(intVar).InnerText Then
                                    If (arr(inti - 1) = "As") Then
                                        If strLineIn.LastIndexOf(",") = strLineIn.IndexOf(arr(inti - 2)) - 2 Then
                                            Dim intPosition As Integer = 2
                                            For Each c In strLineIn
                                                If Not arr(inti - intPosition).StartsWith(VarName(intVar).InnerText) Then
                                                    createErrorLog(strLineIn, fi.Name, intLineNo, arr(inti - intPosition), fi, strErroLogFile)
                                                End If
                                                intPosition = intPosition + 1
                                                If arr(inti - intPosition) = "Dim" Or arr(inti - intPosition) = "Private" Then
                                                    Exit For
                                                End If
                                            Next
                                        Else
                                            If Not arr(inti - 2).StartsWith(VarName(intVar).InnerText) Then
                                                If Not (strLineIn.Contains("Function") And _
                                                arr(arr.Length - 3) = arr(inti - 2)) Then
                                                    createErrorLog(strLineIn, fi.Name, intLineNo, arr(inti - 2), fi, strErroLogFile)
                                                End If
                                            End If

                                        End If
                                    End If

                                End If
                            Next
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End While
            oRead.Close()
            intLineNo = 0
```

but when i m implemnting in c#.net its not working fine, i m confuse to check the c# function coding standerd.

here is the code for c#.net

```
While oRead.Peek <> -1
                strLineIn = oRead.ReadLine().Trim
                intLineNo = intLineNo + 1
                setProgressBar(intLineNo, intLinesCount)
                If strLineIn.StartsWith("/*") Then
                    bCommentLine = True
                ElseIf strLineIn.StartsWith("*/") Then
                    bCommentLine = False
                End If
                Dim arr As String() = Splitline(strLineIn)

                ' code adding
                If Not strLineIn.StartsWith("//") Then
                    If Not strLineIn.Trim.EndsWith(";") And _
                        Not strLineIn.Trim.StartsWith("{") And _
                        Not strLineIn.Trim.StartsWith("}") And _
                        Not strLineIn.StartsWith("//") And _
                        Not strLineIn.Trim.ToString = "" And _
                        Not find(strLineIn.Trim) Then
                        createErrorLog(strLineIn, fi.Name, intLineNo, "No Commnet Line", fi, strErroLogFile)
                    End If
                Else
                    'createErrorLog(processXMLComment(oRead), fi.Name, intLineNo, "No Commnet Line", fi)
                    strLineIn = processXMLComment(oRead, intLineNo)
                End If

                If Not (strLineIn.StartsWith("//") Or strLineIn.StartsWith("///")) And bCommentLine = False Then
                    For intVar As Integer = 0 To DataType.Count - 1
                        If strLineIn.Contains(DataType(intVar).InnerText) Then
                            arr = Splitline(strLineIn)
                            For inti As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 1

                                If arr(inti) = DataType(intVar).InnerText Then

                                    If strLineIn.IndexOf(c) = strLineIn.IndexOf(arr(inti + 1)) + 1 And _
                                    strLineIn.Trim.IndexOf(";") = strLineIn.Length - 1 Then
                                        Dim intPosition As Integer = 1
                                        For Each c In strLineIn
                                            If Not arr(inti + intPosition).StartsWith(VarName(intVar).InnerText) Then
                                                createErrorLog(strLineIn, fi.Name, intLineNo, arr(inti + intPosition), fi, strErroLogFile)
                                            End If
                                            intPosition = intPosition + 1
                                            If arr(inti + intPosition) = "" Then
                                                Exit For
                                            End If
                                        Next
                                    Else

                                        If Not arr(inti + 1).StartsWith(VarName(intVar).InnerText) Then
                                            createErrorLog(strLineIn, fi.Name, intLineNo, arr(inti + 1), fi, strErroLogFile)
                                        End If
                                    End If

                                End If

                            Next
                        End If
                    Next
                End If

            End While
            oRead.Close()
            intLineNo = 0
```

any one please help me out on this.

Comment: "its not working fine" is not a very clear problem description. What is not working? Do you get exceptions (if so, what and where)?

Comment: None of the code you've posted is in C#. What's the question here?

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct answer, the one which help you. This will help others who would be having the same question. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Wouldn't it be better to use existing analysis tools rather than roll your own? These tools should give you some help:

- [FxCop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/)
- [StyleCop](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis)

Answer (score 0):

100% agree with TWith2Sugars, why re-inventing the wheel while some mature tools exist to analyze .NET applications. You can also have a look at the tool [NDepend](http://www.NDepend.com).

Comment: When suggesting your own software, it's recommended that you state your affiliation as part of the post itself rather than just having it as part of your user name to avoid it being flagged as spam. See these posts for further info [link1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/how-do-i-mention-my-own-products-in-answers) [link2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55914/is-it-ok-to-push-your-own-product-on-so)